# ocaml vim : user-setup does not work

Tags: vim, ocaml

I have installed the package user-install for ocaml (via opam)
1) opam install user-setup
2) opam user-setup install  (it will update .vimrc).

But, when invoking vim, I got error due to function not known in .vimrc :
systemlist.

And I fail to see if systemlist is part of vim's function.
Any clue ?

Comment: This is probably obvious, but most likely your version of vim is different than the expected one. I see widely different vim versions across the systems I use, which discourages me from doing any serious customization.

Answer (score 1):

`systemlist()` was introduced in 7.4:248, and a serious bug with it was fixed in 7.4:256, so if it's possible to update your Vim to that patch or later it should solve your problem.